# saving flextable as image crops columns

Tags: r, flextable

I save a flextable using

```
save_as_image(ft,
              path = "file.png",
              zoom = 1 ,
              webshot = "webshot2")
```

I have three flextables being saved, identical in every way except for the data and number of rows, yet when I save them as png's, the last few columns of 2 images are truncated.

Unforntunately, I cannot recreate MRE with random data, and cannot show real data, but is there any possible explanation?

Comment: they don't have the same size probably because the display data have an effect on the size. You should control that size. See https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html#plot-method for a possible option (not with webshot2 but with grid graphics)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. When I try `flextable::gen_grob()` I get `Error: 'gen_grob' is not an exported object from 'namespace:flextable'`,, even after installing `grid`

Comment: you need to update the package from cran (latest version today is 0.8.3)